# Error while recompiling app string.xml

Tags: android, xml

Facing error while recompiling an app.The app was in chinese so I had decompiled it using Advance apktool translated strings.xml but while recompiling it it giving error log attached.

Log Recorded By : Advanced ApkTool v4.1.0 By BDFreak

---

> Blockqu(skipping file '.picasa.ini' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
>       (skipping dir '.picasaoriginals' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
>   F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\tools.apk\res\values\strings.xml:324: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\tools.apk\res\values\public.xml:268: error: Public symbol string/add_screenshot declared here is not defined.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="about_module">about desktop toolbox</string>
    <string name="add_screenshot">increase screenshots options</string>
    <string name="add_screenshot_summary">screenshots option to increase the power menu</string>
    <string name="advanced">advanced</string>
    <string name="advanced_reboot_menu">advanced restart menu</string>
    <string name="advanced_reboot_menu_summary">add more options to "restart" menu</string>
    <string name="all_rotations">enable all the rotation angle</string>
    <string name="all_rotations_summary">allow all rotation angle , including upside down</string>
    <string name="am_pm_style">am pm style</string>
    <string name="am_pm_style_summary">choose am pm style: %s</string>
    <string name="app_browser">browser</string>
    <string name="app_calendar">calendar</string>
    <string name="app_miuigallery">gallery</string>
    <string name="app_mms">sms</string>
    <string name="app_music">music</string>
    <string name="app_phone">phone</string>
    <string name="app_quicksearchbox">quick search bar</string>
    <string name="app_supermarket">app store</string>
    <string name="app_themes">themed</string>
    <string name="app_updater">system update</string>
    <string name="applications">hide checked icon</string>
    <string name="applications_summary">miui system application settings</string>
    <string name="apps_notifications">notice</string>
    <string name="backup_defaults">restore default</string>
    <string name="backup_defaults_restored">the default setting has been restored</string>
    <string name="backup_delete">delete</string>
    <string name="backup_name">backup name</string>
    <string name="backup_no_backups">no backup</string>
    <string name="backup_restore">restore settings</string>
    <string name="backup_restored">restored backup settings</string>
    <string name="backup_restoring">restoring a backup</string>
    <string name="backup_save">save settings</string>
    <string name="backup_save_error">save error !</string>
    <string name="backup_save_successful">successfully saved!</string>
    <string name="battery">battery</string>
    <string name="battery_icon_color">the battery icon color</string>
    <string name="battery_icon_color_summary">setting the battery icon color</string>
    <string name="battery_text_color">battery text color</string>
    <string name="battery_text_color_summary">battery set text color</string>
    <string name="bold_settings_font">set bold text</string>
    <string name="bold_settings_font_summary">systems and applications using bold style</string>
    <string name="browser_autofit_pages">adaptive page</string>
    <string name="browser_autofit_pages_summary">adaptive page option to add the browser</string>
    <string name="buttons">button</string>
    <string name="buttons_summary">key remapping , keystrokes , etc.</string>
    <string name="carrier_label_color">operators label color</string>
    <string name="carrier_label_color_summary">setting operators label color</string>
    <string name="carrier_settings">operators tag</string>
    <string name="clock">clock</string>
    <string name="clock_center">center</string>
    <string name="clock_center_ios7">center (ios 7 style)</string>
    <string name="clock_color_summary">setting the status bar clock color</string>
    <string name="clock_color_title">clock color</string>
    <string name="clock_date_format">date format</string>
    <string name="clock_date_style">date style</string>
    <string name="clock_date_style_summary">"select the date style:
%s"</string>
    <string name="clock_hide">hide clock</string>
    <string name="clock_hide_summary">not in the status bar clock</string>
    <string name="clock_left">left</string>
    <string name="clock_position">clock position</string>
    <string name="clock_position_summary">"choose clock location: 
%s"</string>
    <string name="clock_right">right home ( default )</string>
    <string name="clock_style_hide">hide</string>
    <string name="clock_style_large">l</string>
    <string name="clock_style_small">s</string>
    <string name="cloud_upload_delay">cloud sync delay</string>
    <string name="cloud_upload_delay_summary">"new photos synchronized to the delay time before cloud services millet
%s"</string>
    <string name="color_for_all_icons">icon color</string>
    <string name="color_for_all_icons_summary">the status bar icon color</string>
    <string name="common">desktop</string>
    <string name="config_folder_columns_count">folder number of icons per row</string>
    <string name="config_folder_columns_count_summary">folder number of icons per row after opening: %s</string>
    <string name="config_launcher_icons_size">desktop icons / folders size ratio</string>
    <string name="config_launcher_icons_size_summary">desktop icons / folders size ratio: %s</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop">device properties</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_board">board</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_board_value">ro.product.board</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_brand">brand</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_brand_value">ro.product.brand</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_device">device</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_device_value">ro.product.device</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_model">model</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_model_value">ro.product.model</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_name">name</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_name_value">ro.product.name</string>
    <string name="custom_build_prop_summary">custom settings build.prop parameters</string>
    <string name="custom_carrier_label">custom operators tag</string>
    <string name="custom_carrier_logo">operators tag</string>
    <string name="custom_carrier_logo_summary">alternative operators use image identification tag</string>
    <string name="default_carrier_label">leave blank to use the default carrier tag</string>
    <string name="device">rotation</string>
    <string name="dialog_color_picker">color picker</string>
    <string name="disable_albumart_download">do not download cover</string>
    <string name="disable_albumart_download_summary">prohibits automatically download album cover images</string>
    <string name="disable_numberpicker_sound">touch sound disable dialpad</string>
    <string name="disable_numberpicker_sound_summary">touch sound disable dialpad ( calculator, alarm clock and other tone )</string>
    <string name="disable_safe_volume_warning">disabling safe volume warning</string>
    <string name="disable_safe_volume_warning_summary">when using headphones to listen to music，disable security warning dialog box volume</string>
    <string name="disable_scrolling_cache">scroll cache disabled</string>
    <string name="disable_scrolling_cache_summary">"scroll cache disabled list
you might raise some fluency scrolling list"</string>
    <string name="disable_sms_to_mms_conversion">allow long sms</string>
    <string name="disable_sms_to_mms_conversion_summary">disable automatically converted to mms messages</string>
    <string name="disable_volume_control_sound">disable beep sound sound</string>
    <string name="disable_volume_control_sound_summary">beep sound sounds when adjusting the volume disabled</string>
    <string name="double_click_menu_app">double-click the menu button</string>
    <string name="double_click_menu_app_summary">double-click the menu key to start the selected application</string>
    <string name="double_tap_menu_action">double-click the menu button behavior</string>
    <string name="double_tap_menu_action_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="enable_custom_build_prop">use custom property values</string>
    <string name="enable_custom_build_prop_summary">"the following parameters will be modified on bootup
build.prop file will not be modified"</string>
    <string name="extra_battery_info">additional battery information</string>
    <string name="extra_battery_info_summary">add battery power settings information</string>
    <string name="festival_update_server">recommended sms update server</string>
    <string name="festival_update_server_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="fix_screenshot_position">fixed " screenshots " position</string>
    <string name="fix_screenshot_position_summary">fixed some screenshots options displacement situation. if you have the option to display normal position , please do not turn this option</string>
    <string name="font_size">font size</string>
    <string name="font_size_summary">set the status bar text size: %s</string>
    <string name="framework">more settings</string>
    <string name="framework_summary">more system settings</string>
    <string name="gallery_old_videoplayer">using the system player to play video</string>
    <string name="gallery_old_videoplayer_summary">miuivideoplayer.apk must be installed in / system / app folder</string>
    <string name="headset_notification_icon">hide headset notification icons</string>
    <string name="headset_notification_icon_summary">when headphones are plugged in headphones icon is displayed</string>
    <string name="hide_alarm_icon">hide the clock icon</string>
    <string name="hide_battery_icon">hide the battery icon</string>
    <string name="hide_battery_icon_summary">whether to show the battery icon</string>
    <string name="hide_carrier_label">hide operators tag</string>
    <string name="hide_carrier_label_summary">whether operators tag</string>
    <string name="hide_folders_label">hidden folder labels</string>
    <string name="hide_folders_label_summary">only hide desktop folder text label</string>
    <string name="hide_hotseats_bar">hide the navigation</string>
    <string name="hide_hotseats_bar_summary">it allows you to hide desktop navigation bar to get more space arrangement applications</string>
    <string name="hide_hotseats_label">hide navigation icon labels</string>
    <string name="hide_hotseats_label_summary">only hide the navigation bar at the bottom of the desktop icon labels</string>
    <string name="hide_icons_label">hide desktop icon labels</string>
    <string name="hide_icons_label_summary">only hide desktop icons for all applications under the text label</string>
    <string name="hide_launcher_apps_list">desktop application icon list</string>
    <string name="hide_launcher_apps_summary">you can choose to want to hide the icon on the desktop program</string>
    <string name="hide_launcher_apps_title">hide the selected icon</string>
    <string name="hide_ongoing_ime_switcher">hide input method switcher</string>
    <string name="hide_ongoing_ime_switcher_summary">whether to switch the input method notified when entering</string>
    <string name="hide_roaming_icon">hide roaming icon</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country">country holidays</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_belarus">belarus ( belarus)</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_czech">czech republic(czech republic)</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_kazakhstan">kazakhstan(kazakhstan()</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_original">default ( china )</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_poland">poland ( poland )</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_russia">russia(russia)</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_slovakia">slovakia ( slovakia )</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_turkmenistan">turkmenistan ( turkmenistan )</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_ukraine">ukraine(ukraine)</string>
    <string name="holidays_update_server">holidays updated server</string>
    <string name="holidays_update_server_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="international_t9">t9 search add</string>
    <string name="international_t9_summary">enabling contacts international t9 search</string>
    <string name="key_menu">menu (menu)</string>
    <string name="key_volume">volume keys</string>
    <string name="launch_playback_screen">start the player interface</string>
    <string name="launch_playback_screen_summary">click start to play music when pop pendant interface . by default, the player opens the main interface</string>
    <string name="launcher">desktop</string>
    <string name="launcher_font_size">desktop icons / folders text size</string>
    <string name="launcher_font_size_summary">desktop icons / folders label text size : %s</string>
    <string name="launcher_icons_color">select the icon / folder label color</string>
    <string name="launcher_icons_color_summary">select the desktop icon / folder label text color</string>
    <string name="launcher_summary">desktop -related settings</string>
    <string name="local_yellowpage_database">local yellow pages database</string>
    <string name="local_yellowpage_database_dialog">"china pages database will be cleared.
you need to restart the update t9 index data in the contacts settings.
you want to continue?"</string>
    <string name="local_yellowpage_database_summary">yellow shield china from the server to update and increase contacts marked unknown function</string>
    <string name="localized_measure_units">localization number of units</string>
    <string name="localized_measure_units_summary">"• status bar : network speed (kb / s, mb / s)
• task manager: cleared, available memory (mb, gb)
• data flow : b, kb, mb, gb"</string>
    <string name="lockscreen_rotations">enable lock screen rotation</string>
    <string name="lockscreen_rotations_summary">allows lock screen rotation to landscape mode</string>
    <string name="long_press_menu_action">press the menu key behavior</string>
    <string name="long_press_menu_action_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="long_press_track_skip">volume keys jump track</string>
    <string name="long_press_track_skip_summary">when the screen is turned off long press the volume key to jump track</string>
    <string name="menu_action_custom_app">start the custom applications</string>
    <string name="menu_action_default">default</string>
    <string name="menu_action_previous_app">the launch of an application</string>
    <string name="menu_action_sleep">lock screen</string>
    <string name="menu_action_torch">flashlight</string>
    <string name="mitools_copyright">"any module modifications prohibited.
 burgerz md, copyright © 2015, all rights reserved"</string>
    <string name="miwarning_close">drop out</string>
    <string name="miwarning_continue">carry on</string>
    <string name="miwarning_message">"some models use this program may be no effect, or some features can not be used .
you want to continue?"</string>
    <string name="miwarning_title">welcome to the program</string>
    <string name="mms_unicode_stripping">normalization unicode</string>
    <string name="mms_unicode_stripping_all">remove all unicode character</string>
    <string name="mms_unicode_stripping_leave_intact">remains intact</string>
    <string name="mms_unicode_stripping_non_encodable">unable to remove the encoded characters</string>
    <string name="mms_unicode_stripping_summary">"will unicode character is converted to an ordinary character
mode: %s
( yet) does not work on some devices！"</string>
    <string name="module_desc">"miui6hide icons , modify the label color
[click here to enter the settings take effect after restart]"</string>
    <string name="module_desc_full">"miui6desktop toolbox
the desktop toolbox can hide desktop icons, labels , modify the icon size text color and other functions."</string>
    <string name="module_name">desktop toolbox</string>
    <string name="multiline_labels">multiple lines icon / folders tab</string>
    <string name="multiline_labels_summary">multi-line desktop icons / folders tag</string>
    <string name="national_roaming">domestic data roaming</string>
    <string name="national_roaming_summary">but open domestic roaming data services</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar">navigation bar</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_color">navigation bar color</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_color_summary">navigation bar background color</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_height">navigation bar height</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_height_landscape">the height of the navigation bar</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_height_summary">height : %s</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_override">override default</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_override_summary">navigation bar adjustment</string>
    <string name="navigation_bar_width">navigation bar width</string>
    <string name="network_speed_exp_statusbar">current network speed</string>
    <string name="network_speed_exp_statusbar_summary">the status bar displays the current network speed</string>
    <string name="none">(no)</string>
    <string name="notif_reboot">reboot</string>
    <string name="notif_reboot_required">restart for the changes to take effect</string>
    <string name="notif_reboot_required_message">you need to restart to apply changes</string>
    <string name="notif_reboot_required_title">need to restart</string>
    <string name="notif_soft_reboot">soft reboot</string>
    <string name="notif_torch_on">flashlight</string>
    <string name="notification_bubble_apps">application list</string>
    <string name="notifications">notice</string>
    <string name="one_color_for_all_icons">all icons single color</string>
    <string name="one_color_for_all_icons_summary">let all the icons on the status bar using a single color</string>
    <string name="own_carrier_logo">select custom logo</string>
    <string name="own_carrier_logo_2">select custom identified logo</string>
    <string name="own_carrier_logo_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="power">about</string>
    <string name="power_cancel">cancel</string>
    <string name="power_reboot">reboot</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_bootloader">reboot into the brush machine mode (fastboot)</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_hot">quick restart</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_normal">normal restart</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_options">restart menu</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_recovery">reboot into recovery mode (recovery)</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_switch_system">switching system ( millet phone only)</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_system_1">reboot the system</string>
    <string name="power_reboot_system_2">reboot the system two</string>
    <string name="preference_app_picker_search">search applications</string>
    <string name="press_color_to_apply">tap the color to apply</string>
    <string name="quicksearchbox_marketplace">search market</string>
    <string name="quicksearchbox_marketplace_summary">"search for the following markets :
%s"</string>
    <string name="screenshot_delay">screenshot delay ( ms)</string>
    <string name="select_carrier_logo">select identity</string>
    <string name="select_carrier_logo_2">select identify two</string>
    <string name="select_carrier_logo_summary">%s</string>
    <string name="set_launcher_icons_color">select the icon / folder label color</string>
    <string name="set_launcher_icons_color_summary">use custom icons / folders label color</string>
    <string name="show_battery_text">icon appears next to the text</string>
    <string name="show_battery_text_summary">display battery percentage</string>
    <string name="show_navigation_bar">show navigation bar</string>
    <string name="show_navigation_bar_summary">within the display screen buttons (nexus style )</string>
    <string name="show_notification_bubble">display notification bubble</string>
    <string name="show_notification_bubble_summary">bubble notification is displayed on the application's icon</string>
    <string name="signal_bars_color">signal color</string>
    <string name="signal_bars_color_2">signal color two</string>
    <string name="signal_bars_color_summary">setting the mobile network signal indicator color</string>
    <string name="signal_bars_color_summary_2">setting the mobile network signal indicator color ( card b)</string>
    <string name="sound">voice</string>
    <string name="sound_summary">voice -related settings</string>
    <string name="statusbar">status bar</string>
    <string name="statusbar_background_color">background color</string>
    <string name="statusbar_background_color_summary">the status bar background color</string>
    <string name="statusbar_common">general options</string>
    <string name="statusbar_set_background_color">change the background color</string>
    <string name="statusbar_set_background_color_summary">allows background color modify the status bar</string>
    <string name="statusbar_summary">modify status bar</string>
    <string name="statusbar_text_family">font style</string>
    <string name="statusbar_text_family_summary">select the status bar font style : %s</string>
    <string name="statusbar_text_style">font style</string>
    <string name="statusbar_text_style_summary">select the status bar font style: %s</string>
    <string name="supermarket_disable_autoupdates_check">disable check for updates</string>
    <string name="supermarket_disable_autoupdates_check_summary">disable the automatic check for updates</string>
    <string name="supermarket_reverse_tabs_order">reverse tab order</string>
    <string name="supermarket_reverse_tabs_order_summary">tags will modify order: management , classification , ranking , fine</string>
    <string name="swap_long_press_skip_keys">switching button</string>
    <string name="swap_long_press_skip_keys_summary">when switching tone skip track</string>
    <string name="take_screenshot">screenshots</string>
    <string name="text_large">large</string>
    <string name="text_medium">in</string>
    <string name="text_small">small</string>
    <string name="themes_replace_lunar_dates">replace lunar date</string>
    <string name="themes_replace_lunar_dates_summary">try to find topic lunar date and replaced by the gregorian calendar ( lock screen )</string>
    <string name="themes_reverse_tabs_order">reverse tab order</string>
    <string name="themes_reverse_tabs_order_summary">tags will modify order: i , classification , ranking , fine</string>
    <string name="time_10_min">10 minutes</string>
    <string name="time_1_hour">1 hour</string>
    <string name="time_1_min">1 min (default )</string>
    <string name="time_30_min">30 minute</string>
    <string name="time_30_sec">30 second</string>
    <string name="time_5_min">5 minute</string>
    <string name="typeface_family_condensed">compact</string>
    <string name="typeface_family_light">lighter</string>
    <string name="typeface_family_regular">usually</string>
    <string name="typeface_family_thin">fine</string>
    <string name="typeface_style_bold">bold face</string>
    <string name="typeface_style_italic">italic type</string>
    <string name="typeface_style_normal">general</string>
    <string name="units_b">b</string>
    <string name="units_gb">gb</string>
    <string name="units_kb">kb</string>
    <string name="units_kbs">kb/s</string>
    <string name="units_mb">mb</string>
    <string name="units_mbs">mb/s</string>
    <string name="units_s">s</string>
    <string name="unlink_notification_volume">volume settings are not synchronized</string>
    <string name="unlink_notification_volume_summary">separate ringtones & amp; notice the volume settings</string>
    <string name="updater_disable_autoupdates_check">disable check for updates</string>
    <string name="updater_disable_autoupdates_check_summary">disable the automatic check for updates</string>
    <string name="updater_english_changelog">display english update log</string>
    <string name="updater_english_changelog_summary">english forced display update log</string>
    <string name="use_own_carrier_logo">custom operator identification</string>
    <string name="use_own_carrier_logo_summary">you can choose your own carrier logo</string>
    <string name="vol_key_cursor">volume keys cursor control</string>
    <string name="vol_key_cursor_reverse">switching button</string>
    <string name="vol_key_cursor_reverse_summary">exchange volume keys control the cursor when</string>
    <string name="vol_key_cursor_summary">use the volume keys to control the cursor input</string>
    <string name="volume_notification_description">notice</string>
    <string name="volume_ring_description">ring</string>
    <string name="volume_step">volume step</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_alarm">alarm volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_bluetooth">bluetooth volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_music">music volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_notification">notification volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_ring">ringer volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_system">media volume</string>
    <string name="volume_steps_voice_call">call volume</string>
    <string name="preference_app_picker_none">(no)</string>
    <string name="show_clock_date">show status bar date</string>
    <string name="show_clock_date_summary">in the status bar next to the clock display date</string>
    <string name="holidays_selector_country_german">germany</string>
    <string name="statusbar_title">status bar</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Post your string.xml. Pay attention to the error.

Comment: Added string.xml that i translated.

Comment: It looks like you have 2 errors, one in `strings.xml` and one in `pulbic.xml`. Did you check the lines that have those issues?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have an error at strings.xml at line #324

This is that line:

```
<string name="unlink_notification_volume_summary">separate ringtones & amp; notice the volume settings</string>
```

you have an unnecessary space between **&** and **amp;**.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem :)